# Fetch Data From Repeater Control On the base of Selected Record

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Hello Everyone I have a repeater control in my asp.net web page. I want to select month from the the repeater control and from the base of that month I want to get the all the data that I post on that month Here is the source code of repeater control.

```
 <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" 
                onitemcommand="Repeater1_ItemCommand">

            <ItemTemplate>
            <ul class="archive">
            <li><a href="#">
                 <%#Eval("mnth") %> 
            &nbsp; <%#Eval("yr") %><span>(<%#Eval("totalcount") %>)</span>
                <%--<asp:Label ID="Label6" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("mnth") %>">&nbsp; 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("yr") %>"></asp:Label><span> ( 
                    <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text="<%#Eval("totalcount") %>"></asp:Label> ) </span> </a></li>--%>
              </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>

            </asp:Repeater>
```

Here is the code that I use to Bind the repeater control

```
  private void BindPostCounts()
    {
        SqlCommand cmdBindCounts = new SqlCommand("CountBlogPost_sp", con);
        cmdBindCounts.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlDataAdapter daBindCounts = new SqlDataAdapter(cmdBindCounts);
        DataSet dsBindCount = new DataSet();
        daBindCounts.Fill(dsBindCount);
        Repeater1.DataSource = dsBindCount;
        Repeater1.DataBind();


    }
```

And This is the table which I am using

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BlogPost](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Title] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [Blogpost] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [Paramlink] [varchar](500) NULL,
    [PostDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActive] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO

SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
```

Now base on month selected I want to get the Data that I post on that Month Please tell me on which event I have to Work

Comment: please specify information regarding table from which you are fetching data

Comment: @Rony please check i edit my question add my table

Comment: @AzadChohan - make use of ID with hidden field....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this approach. Put a LinkButton inside your repeater (example bellow):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">

    <ItemTemplate>
        <ul class="archive">
            <li>
                <asp:LinkButton runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("mnth") %>' CommandArgument='<%#Eval("mnth") %>' OnCommand="OnMonthSelected"></asp:LinkButton>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

and then in OnCommand event handler get month value and get all blog posts by month.

```
protected void OnMonthSelected(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    int month = Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument);

    //get blog posts for month
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You Use Two repeater parent and child
In the parent repeater, attach a method to the OnItemDataBound event and in the method, find the nested repeater and bind data according month.

Example (.aspx):

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ParentRepeater" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ItemBound">
<ItemTemplate>
    <!-- Repeated data -->
<asp:Label id="monthlabel" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Rating") %>' Runat="server"/>
    <asp:Repeater ID="ChildRepeater" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <!-- Nested repeated data -->
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Example (.cs):

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    ParentRepeater.DataSource = ...;
    ParentRepeater.DataBind();
}}

protected void ItemBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs args)
{
if (args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || args.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
{
var Monthname =((Label)e.Item.FindControl("monthlabel")).Text
    Repeater childRepeater = (Repeater)args.Item.FindControl("ChildRepeater");
    childRepeater.DataSource = ...;
    childRepeater.DataBind();
}
```

}